# zeromq load balacing in "divide and conquer"

Tags: python, message-queue, zeromq

I am reproducing the [Divide & Conquer example](http://zguide2.zeromq.org/page:all#Divide-and-Conquer) of zeroMQ of the zguide2. It uses a ventilator to push out tasks to several workers which send the result to a sink.

This all works fine. However, if I am simulating a slower client or very unevenly balanced tasks the running time is far from optimal. This is, e.g., possible by adding the lines

```
if(task_nbr % cpu_count() == 0):
        workload *= 4
```

after `workload = random.randint(1, 100)` in the [ventilator](http://zguide2.zeromq.org/py:taskvent).

I tried to reduce to high-water mark of the receiver (worker) and the sender (ventilator) but without improving the runtime.

The mistake might be in the choice of the socket-type "PUB"/"PULL"?

I can attach a minimal-working-example if wanted but due to the worker-ventilator-sink structure it's a bit lengthy (~150 lines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it is better to use [ROUTER and REQ sockets](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#ROUTER-Broker-and-REQ-Workers). This is possible in python with

```
client = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
```

and

```
worker = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
```

A fully worked out example by Jeremy Avnet can be found [in the zguide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:rtreq). One can observe that even with the code of the question added the runtime will be close to optimal.

Why this works is described also in the in the section 
[The Load Balancing Pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#The-Load-Balancing-Pattern):

> workers send a "ready" message when they start, and after they finish each task. The broker reads these messages one-by-one. Each time it reads a message, it is from the last used worker. And because we're using a ROUTER socket, we get an identity that we can then use to send a task back to the worker